# List all video on youtube

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-api

I'm looking for a way to list every video on youtube. you have any ideas for it?

```
YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(YouTubeQuery.DefaultVideoUri);
query.Query = "";     //<-Research key//
query.OrderBy = "viewCount";
query.SafeSearch = YouTubeQuery.SafeSearchValues.None;

Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(query);
```

In this way, youtube return only 1.000.000 of result.

Comment: probably the youtube api only allows a maximum return of 1000000 videos, but why would you want more?

Comment: According to this estimate: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpYCUn22l-E Assuming 2.89 _billion_ videos, and say 100 bytes _per_ `Video` info to transfer, that's approximately 269 _gigabytes_. Good luck with that!

Comment: Apart from the fact that by the time your first query is returned there will already have been a bunch of new videos uploaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From *[`Youtube Api`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference)* page;

> The  tag has a maximum value of 1,000,000. As
>   such, if the tag value is 1,000,000, you can be sure that there are not
>   exactly one million results but rather that there are so many matches
>   that we just stopped counting. In addition, the maximum value for this tag is 1,000,000.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube is correctly setting a maximum number of results to return.
According to the YouTube statistics there exist 120 million videos that have been identified to contain copyrighted material. The total number of videos was about 140 million *in 2008*.

Assuming an average of 8 characters per video title, transfering the titles of these 140 million videos alone would result in a download the size of about one GB, the overhead of the data structure not factored in.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem of your code. I guess that the server returns at most 1000000 results, since it's an interesting number, don't you think so? google has established a limit to avoid recalculating the total number of videos anytime or for another unknown reason.

Cheers,